# Conjugacy of subgroups of free groups

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $F(X)$ be the free group on a finite set $X$. Suppose that $H \subseteq F(X)$ is a subgroup where $[F(X):H]$ is finite.

What can we say about the size of $[F(X):N(H)]$ where $N(H)$ is the normaliser of ? (Other than the trivial $[F(X):H] = [F(X):N(H)] [N(H):H]$)

That is, what can we say about the number of subgroups conjugate to $H$?

Comment: A subgroup of finite index in a free group can be visualized as a certain finite graph. The number of conjugates of this subgroup is the number of orbits of the action of the automorphism group of this graph on its vertices. Can you ask a more specific question? As far as I know it can be any number between $1$ and the index.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan If you could provide some reference to this graph construction and why the number of orbits of the automorphism group is equal to size of the conjugacy orbit I would happily accept it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Furthermore, I heard about the relation of these subgroups to free loops in topological spaces? If you have any reference to this please add it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should've said "as far as I know it can be any divisor of the index."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classical result (which can be seen topologically) asserts that if $|X|=r$ and $[F(X):H]=n$ then $H$ is a free group over $nr-(n-1)$ generators. It is quoted as a result of Schreier in this paper (p. 188) :

http://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v1/cjm1949v01.0187-0190.pdf

At the end (theorem 5.2) you have a theorem giving a formula for computing the number of subgroups of index $n$ in $F_r$.

It is far from what you are asking... As @Qiaochu Yuan said, it is hard to say better than the number of conjugates can be any divisor of $n$ so you cannot expect a better answer.

How does appear the group $H$? Do you have a set of free generators for it (in terms of the generators of $F_r$)? If you do, you might get a more accurate answer...

If you don't, as @Qiaochu Yuan said it is usually better to understand free groups and their finite index subgroups with topology. It boils down to give some wedge of circles covered with another wedge of circles. Some references for this :

https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch1.pdf

Combinatorial group theory, Lyndon and Schupp.

Comment: Correction to: "It boils down to give some wedge of circles covered with another wedge of circles" --- the covering graph need not be a wedge of circles.

Comment: "If Moses supposes that roses are the only graphs whose fundamental group is free, then Moses supposes erroneously" (apologies to Comden and Green, lyricists for "Singing in the Rain").